# Hide horizontal scrollbar in IE 7 and below

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6, internet-explorer-7

Basically, I'm having trouble removing the horizontal scrollbar in Internet Explorer 7 and Below. I've tried the code below and It seems to work fine in every browser except IE.

```
overflow-x: hidden;
```

The even bigger problem is that, even though the scrollbar isn't even removed, it seems to completely screw the layout.. It somehow hides the majority of the page content in boxes  2 and 3? It also.. adds a second vertical scrollbar which moves relatively/absolute positioned items down?!
I did contemplate just leaving the scrollbar in IE via a specified stylesheet, but even that seems to be messing with the page?

The website is on a test directory [here](http://openyourheart.org.uk/test/index.html).. 
I'll post the stylesheet in a comment below.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance, hope you can help!
Bradley

Comment: http://openyourheart.org.uk/test/style.css

Comment: Wow man. I can't even get it to run on ie6 or ie7. Just freezes up and I have to force close. You might want to seriously consider conditional stylesheets as suggested by Joseph.

Comment: The crashes should be sorted now.. I tried a conditional stylesheet, but it still seemed to be influenced by the main sheet? Can you apply a style in a stylesheet specified only for IE?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting a static width on a container, giving it sufficient height, and then setting overflow:hidden for the entire container? Not sure if that would play well with your JS scrolling, but it might be a move in the right direction.

Oh, and any solution given will probably be insufficient for IE6. That beast just wasn't made for pretty layouts. I guess as an alternative, define a conditional stylesheet for that and/or IE7 for a less complex layout.

Comment: any chance you could you give me an example? Cheers