# Horizontal scrollbar appears only in IE7 even with overflow:hidden being set

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, horizontal-scrolling

I'm banging my head on this one.

I have a disturbing horizontal scrollbar that appears only when browsing my site in IE7:
http://www.regia.it

I have tried and tried to stop this from happening by using `overflow:hidden` on my `div`s but for some reason I just can't seem to find what is causing the problem.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Tested with IE8 in compatibility view, no scrollbar here. The only thing wrong I saw was the menu, that was vertical instead of horizontal. Can you post a screen shot?

Comment: Take a look at this SO Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941172/hide-horizontal-scrollbar-in-ie-7-and-below

Comment: Here's a screenshot in IE7:http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2899749/screen.png

Comment: I have been trying the overflow-x: hidden property on the body tag with no success.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This does seem odd. I am assuming you don't mind if the page is not horizontally scrollable even on small screens, since you have tried to use:

```
body{overflow-x: hidden;}
```

In which case if you apply it to `html` rather than `body` it should do the trick:

```
html{overflow-x: hidden;}
```

I wouldn't really want to implement this long term, but if you are looking for a quick fix this should be ok as a temporary measure until you can work out what is going wrong. I would also put it in a conditional comment so as not to ruin the experience for the majority of people on modern browsers.

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
    Link to alternate style sheet
    OR
    <style> /*CSS in here*/ </style>
<![endif]-->
```

**EDIT :** I have found the cause of the issue, so there is no need to use the above workaround. As I had suspected the issue was related to absolute and relative positioning.

You just need to remove `position:relative` from `.grid_2` and `.grid_12` and the scrollbar will disappear.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I've precisely done just a couple mins before your answer and did fix the bug. As you said I would have hoped for a better solution, but this will do! Thank you.

Comment: @milksamsa: Happy I could help and glad you didn't have to use the reduced usability workaround.

Comment: +1 for the edit about `position:relative` -- that was news to me and saved me some trouble.  I really think that's the ultimate solution -- hiding overflow makes it go away even when it may be necessary!

Answer (score 1):

I came across this vexing issue too. I had a table in a div, and these were inside an outer div. When I removed the style to make the inner div width:100%, my 'IE7 only' scrollbar situation disappeared.

Hopefully that is somewhat helpful.