# Disabled scroll bar (grayed out), except in IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, scroll, internet-explorer-7

I have an overlay and to disable scrolling while the scroll bar is still visible (*grayed out*), I used:

**CSS**

```
html.noscroll {
    position: fixed;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    width: 100%;
}
```

It works properly in IE8 and higher, but in IE7 the scroll bar is still enabled, and I can still scroll through the page.

Does anybody have an idea how I can solve this problem?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7435328/horizontal-scrollbar-appears-only-in-ie7-even-with-overflowhidden-being-set

Comment: Try adding !important to the rule to override the browser stylesheet rule; which should work if IE7 has an important rule saying the contrary.

Answer (score 0):

overflow:scroll makes IE displaying the scrollbar in all cases, even if it is not needed. That's what you want to do ?

IE6 & 7 are known to have scrolls issues when coupled with 'position:relative' or 'width:100%' and margins.

Try with

```
width: 80%;
```

If scrolls are correctly greyed, you probably have a margin/padding issue. If it changed nothing, try changing the position.