# Chrome: Scrollbar is showing on Windows but NOT Mac

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, overflow

I have this div with an overflowX:

```
<div style={{ overflowX: 'scroll' }}>
   Some Content
</div>
```

It looks like this on Chrome (Windows):

[image]

But on Chrome (Mac) it looks like this:
[image]

Even though it's the latest version of Chrome, on Windows the scrollbars appears with the arrows even though there is nothing to scroll.

On Mac, the scroll only appears when there is something to scroll, and the ugly arrows do NOT show.

How can I may the scrolling look on Windows as it does on Mac with Chrome?

Answer (score 3):

You can do that by changing the system preferences in mac to this
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Probably not useful anymore for you, but if someone needs it you should use overflowX: auto

`overflow: scroll` forces the scrollbars to appear even if they are not needed. Note that is not completely true if you are on a mac, depending on your computer's settings the browser might try to make them appear just when scrolling.

`overflow: auto` makes the scrollbar appear only when needed.

Answer (score 0):

Have your tried `<div style="overflow-x: scroll;">`? It seems as if you're using [OverflowX](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_overflowx.asp)  which is can be used in other contexts, such as Javascript.

Comment: Unless I haven't understood what you're doing, double brackets isn't standard for XML-style markup, including HTML. I might be wrong, but it seems as if you're confused. Does this work on Chrome? It seems to work for me on Firefox and Chrome alike. http://jsfiddle.net/ep615kzq/3/

Comment: That's just JSX

Comment: Ah, I see. Have you tried `overflow-x: auto;` instead of scroll. Does it work for you? Also, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20482557/disabled-scroll-bar-grayed-out-except-in-ie7

Comment: I have - no difference